# ActionLink with parameters not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I am trying to call an action result with parameters but they all show us null?

Here is my ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "APNewQuote", "APQuotes", new {OENum = Model.OENumber, QuoteNumber = Model.QuoteNumber, ClaimNumber = Model.ClaimNumber, MotorBodyRepairer = Model.MotorBodyRepairer, VehicleRegistration = Model.VehicleRegistration, VehicleMakeId = Model.VehicleMakeId, VehicleModelId = Model.VehicleModelId, VehicleRangeId = Model.VehicleRangeId}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary niceButton" })
```

And in my controller:

```
public ActionResult APNewQuote(string OENum, string QuoteNumber, string ClaimNumber, string MotorBodyRepairer, string VehicleRegistration, int? vehicleMakeId, int? vehicleModelId, int? vehicleRangeId)
{
 //Do things with the variables passed in

 APNewQuoteViewModel viewModel = new APNewQuoteViewModel
 {
  OENumber = OENumber,
  QuoteNumber = QuoteNumber,
  ClaimNumber = ClaimNumber,
  MotorBodyRepairer = MotorBodyRepairer,
  VehicleRegistration = VehicleRegistration,
  VehicleMakeId = vehicleMakeId,
  VehicleMakes = vehicleMakes,
  VehicleModelId = vehicleModelId,
  VehicleModels = vehicleModels,
  VehicleRanges = vehicleRanges,
  VehicleRangeId = vehicleRangeId,
  Date = Date
 };

 return View(viewModel);
}
```

The above method is used to initialy display the view so its fine if all the input parameters are null, but when i call the action Result again i need to use those parameters so they can't be null.

I can run my project i just revive null for everything when i click on my action Link, it does move to the right method.

Comment: Did you verify that the model is passed to your view.

Comment: @Pomster..are you using MVC 3 ? I too faced the similar issue

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu I am using MVC 4

Comment: @Pomster..just check whether you are able to get info to controller by using Request object?

Comment: @BigDaddy Yes i have added "@model SpendDirect.WebUI.Models.ViewModels.APNewQuoteViewModel" at the top of my view, I use dropdownFor and editorFor so im sure the model is passed to the view.

Comment: @Pomster...good, I would just be sure the other values (OENumber, etc.) are set in your controller before you return the view.

Comment: Is the link created correctly?

Comment: @BigDaddy Ok i have set all the values in the controller and then pass the model to my view, how ever when i edit things and move back into the method everything is still null?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları What do you mean by this?

Comment: What's the URL of the link? Is that created correctly?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları It moves to the correct method in the correct controller, its just the parameters never pass through.

Comment: Do you see the parameter values in querystring?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try accessing ike this : `Request.Params[0]`

Comment: @Pomster..i just wanted you to check if your model values are reaching controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below MVC Helper code generates the link with the query string

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "APNewQuote", "APQuotes", new {OENum = Model.OENumber, 
     QuoteNumber = Model.QuoteNumber, ClaimNumber = Model.ClaimNumber, 
     MotorBodyRepairer = Model.MotorBodyRepairer, VehicleRegistration = 
     Model.VehicleRegistration, VehicleMakeId = Model.VehicleMakeId, 
     VehicleModelId = Model.VehicleModelId, VehicleRangeId = Model.VehicleRangeId}, 
    new { @class = "btn btn-primary niceButton" })
```

i.e

```
<a href="/APNewQuote/Add?OENum=val1&QuoteNumber=val2,etc">APQuotes</a>
```

Then your controller method should be able to serve for `[HttpGet]` by default. In case, if you decorated with `[HttpPost]` only please add `HttpGet` verb too.

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult APNewQuote(string OENum, string QuoteNumber, string ClaimNumber, string MotorBodyRepairer, string VehicleRegistration, int? vehicleMakeId, int? vehicleModelId, int? vehicleRangeId)
{

}
```